# Mocking - zero interactions

Tags: java, mocking

I have written a test to verify that a public method in my class is called. My test is failing as follows. Can anyone tell me why this happening?

> Wanted but not invoked: `mockMyClass.runThis();
>
> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

```
class MyClass{
  public void myMethod(){    
    runThis("hello");
  }
}

public void runThis(String str){
  return;
}
```

Test class

```
@Mock
MyClass mockMyClass;

MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

@Test
public void test(){
  myClass.myMethod();
  verify(mockMyClass).runThis(anyString());
}
```

Comment: Is the runThis method within MyClass private?

Answer (score 2):

You're not invoking against your *mock*, but rather the real class. You need to generate a mock, and then invoke on that mock. Try something like:

```
MyClass mock = mock(MyClass.class);  // I'm using the methods rather than annotation here
mock.myMethod();
```

and assert on that. I'm not quite sure in the above where `runThis()` is, though. If it's on a contained class, then *that's* the thing to need to mock. If it's on the same class, then you can't use a *mock* per se, since the mock substitutes all functionality, and perhaps the Mockito `spy()` mechanism would be of use here. S[ection 13 of the doc](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html) advises more on this.

Comment: I have tried called myMethod via my mock and with the @Mock annotation but when I add a debug point to the first line of myMethod, it is not invoked.